# Maven dependency randomly not recognized

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, dependencies

I am working on a Java Spring Boot web application using HTML and Thymeleaf as my front end. The issue I am having is that my ThymeleafConfig class will randomly have an error when I try to run my project. I will explain in more detail below, but first here is my code.

Pom.xml dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
     <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

ThymeleafConfig class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;

@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect() {
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }
}
```

So to explain further, my code will be good (according to my IDE), containing no errors on any of my lines, ready to run. I will run my application class to run my project, and I will get compilation errors.

IntelliJ will automatically open the file that has the error in it, which is my `ThymeleafConfig` class. When the error is present, the import statement `import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;` line will be greyed out and not recognized. causing errors in the class.

To fix it, I right-click my `pom.xml` file -> Maven -> Reimport. This will reimport all of my dependencies and everything will go back to normal.

I also want to stress that this does not happen every time I run the application. Sometimes it will happen 3 times in a row, other times I will run it 5+ times before the error shows up again.

I have tried `mvn clean` which did not fix the issue. I have also moved the dependency to a different line in the pom.xml file.

edit:
Here is my Application.java class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

To run the application I right click this file and click the run 'Application' button.

Comment: Could you please also tell us how exactly you build / run your app? It would seem to me you're somehow removing the libraries / breaking the classpath.

Comment: Of course - see edit

Comment: I have 15+ other dependencies in my pom.xml - all are behaving as they should. It's just this Thymeleaf-security-4 dependency that has an issue

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot already includes thymeleaf (a different version) and you are probably having multiple versions on the classpath. Spring Boot is pretty clear about thymeleaf on its documentation:

### [Spring boot 1.4.2's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-thymeleaf-3) on using a thymeleaf 3.0.0

> By default, spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf uses Thymeleaf 2.1. If you
>   are using the spring-boot-starter-parent, you can use Thymeleaf 3 by
>   overriding the thymeleaf.version and thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version
>   properties, for example:
>
> ```
> <properties>
>     <thymeleaf.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
>     <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.0.3</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
> </properties>
> ```
>
> ...
>
> If you are using any of the other auto-configured Thymeleaf Extras
>   (Spring Security, Data Attribute, or Java 8 Time) you should also
>   override each of their versions to one that is compatible with
>   Thymeleaf 3.0.

If you look at [**spring-boot-dependency's pom on github**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml), the thymeleaf properties are:

> ```
> <thymeleaf.version>2.1.5.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>          
> <thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version>
>
> <thymeleaf-extras-conditionalcomments.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-conditionalcomments.version>
>
> <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>1.4.0</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
>
> <thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute.version>1.3</thymeleaf-extras-data-attribute.version>
>
> <thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version>2.1.0.RELEASE</thymeleaf-extras-java8time.version>
> ```

#### Recap

I believe you would need to at least define the following properties (perhaps a few more to avoid a mismatch of versions?):

- thymeleaf.version
- thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4.version

Comment: Where exactly would I define this `<properties>` snippet you provided? In the pom itself or in a separate config file?

Comment: In your pom, just as you would normally define properties.